# Force autocomplete suggestions for file paths

Tags: phpstorm, phalcon

I am currently working on a controller file for a Phalcon project. I like how PhpStorm gives you autocomplete suggestions when writing a src or href value in an HTML file. I was wondering, is possible to enable autocomplete suggestions when adding resources in a controller? 
 
This is what happens when I force autocomplete suggestions(Ctrl + Space) 
[image: autocomplete suggestions not working]
This is what I would like to happen.
[image: autocomplete suggestions working]

**EDIT:** I should also note that I have marked the folder, containing all my resources(ie. CSS, javascript, and images), as the "Resource root".

> **RE: EDIT**
> This does not affect availability of this feature/functionality in any way as "Resource roots" are used for path resolutions/validation and not for actual "offer this functionality or hide it" choice. 
> [-LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone)

Comment: PHPStorm has no way to know that you want to write a filepath here. For him, it's just a string.

Comment: Well, @Protectator is right -- there is no real way of automatically providing such functionality. But .. you can forcibly enable it **manually for each particular place** (should last until file or project is closed). 1) Have some code, e.g. `$s = ['a' => 'aaa'];` 2) Place caret inside `aaa` string (it has to be 3 or more characters, based on my observations) 3) Invoke shortcut to bring Quick Fix menu (`Alt+Enter` on Windows) 4) Choose `Inject language or reference` from appeared menu 5) Choose `File Reference` from next menu 6) Enjoy.

Comment: I understand that it's just a string. I am just looking for a way to confirm that I am writing the correct paths as I am writing them.

Comment: You could also just click "copy reference" on the desired file and paste it where you want it.

Comment: @LazyOne This worked. Please write your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no real way of automatically providing such functionality in random string as it's hard to guess that file path is expected in this particular place (function parameters is different case -- here some hinting mechanics (special annotation) may work).

But .. you can forcibly enable it **manually for each particular place** (should last until file or project is closed):

1. Have some code, e.g. `$someVar = ['css' => 'aaa'];`
2. Place caret inside `aaa` string (it has to be 3 or more characters, based on my observations, otherwise option in #4 will not be present -- must be some sort of optimisation/limitation from IDE side)
3. Invoke shortcut to bring "Quick Fix" menu (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> on Windows)
4. Choose `Inject language or reference` from appeared menu
5. Choose `File Reference` from next menu
6. Start using it (<kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>)

---

> EDIT: I should also note that I have marked the folder, containing all my resources(ie. CSS, javascript, and images), as the "Resource root".

This does not affect availability of this feature/functionality in any way as "Resource roots" are used for path resolutions/validation and not for actual "offer this functionality or hide it" choice.