# PhpStorm autocomplete type string image

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have a simple question :
when I put an `IMG` tag it autocomplete with picture on project :

```
<img src="/img/logos/mylogo.png">
```

But I have a function like this :

```
/**
* @param string $img
* @param mixed $opts
* @param mixed $attrs
* @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
*/
function picture(string $img,$opts=[],$attrs=[]){
   ....
}
```

And I want autocomplete with (img) resources files dir :
 I think that I have to modify this line

```
  * @param string $img
```

but I don't know what to do.

I want a "resource files autocomplete" in PhpStorm (or a generic directive compatible with all IDE).

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm right 100% but unfortunately with default settings / plugins you cannot do that. Alternatively you can wrote your own plugin for that.

Comment: There is no such standard PHPDoc (that would work across IDEs) .. especially when applied on function signature. When calling that function/method .. you could manually inject File Reference completion (see below). If it would be some SQL or alike language -- you could force it by placing `/** @lang MySQL */` comment (*adjust language as needed*) just before the parameter (when **calling** this method) .. but it does not seem to work for File References - see this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20028

Comment: But in general this question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39133809/783119

Comment: Other than that -- custom plugin (not sure if any existing supports it).