# PhpStorm, file or directory path completion relative to project root

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

Do you know any good way to make PhpStorm complete file or directory path location?

I know code completion works when using relative to `__DIR__` paths like so:

```
__DIR__ . '/../../../bin'
```

but I would like to it to work relative to project root in constant or directory returned by some method. Or really any other way that would do not require refactor of path when moving file around. I could provide some kind of PHPDoc to help PhpStorm doing it (by relative path or in other way, I can do it in one place).

Can you share any good way to completion of file path to work in that way?

I use Symfony framework with Symfony plugin, maybe this could provide this functionality?

For example:

```
$a = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/';
```

I put cursor after slash and press <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> it should have show completion options. So that it could be completed to:

```
$a = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/AppKernel.php';
```

and then after clicking <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> on `AppKernel` it should show this file in project panel, like would `__DIR__` equivalent do:

[image]

Currently in `$a = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/';` code completion do not work:

[image]

Comment: Any example of such usage? In Symfony you should base on `$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();` (or `%kernel.root_dir%` parameter) which is `app` directory by default.

Comment: @JakubMatczak I updated question to show examples

Comment: @LPodolski You may try submitting a ticket for Symfony plugin -- this is the most likely where it can be fixed. The reason is -- completion after `__DIR__` is sort of hard coded into IDE (the `__DIR__` works as a trigger) .. they unlikely will write a code to recognize framework specific sequence -- that's what Symfony plugin might be able to do (no guarantee though -- just my generic thoughts).

Comment: @LPodolski On another hand -- you can inject "File Reference" helper into any string .. but 1) it's a temporary injection AFAIK 2) you need to type at very least 3 chars before this intention will become available. You can see more about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39133809/783119